# microsoft visual c++ 2015 redistributable package Setup fails 0x80240017

Tags: visual-c++, xampp

I try to use install microsoft visual c++ 2015 redistributable package but I error due to installation "Setup fails 0x80240017". Can anyone help me ?

Comment: What OS (and service pack level if applicable) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue with your systems' Windows Update status generally, and not specifically the Visual C++ REDIST package--which does trigger some Windows Updates if they are missing from your system.

Here are some general Windows Update troubleshooting steps you should try:

- Run SFC. See [KB 929833](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system)
- Run the System Update Readiness Tool or DISM. See [KB 947821](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness)